# SQL to_char() | Convert minutes into a string of size 2

Tags: sql, postgresql, to-char, datetime-select

Using postgres, I am trying to convert minutes to a string consisting of two characters.

For example, if the code outputs 0, I want to convert this to '00'.

```
EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

I've tried this so far but it adds a space in front. So instead of getting '00' I get ' 00'

```
to_char(EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '00')
```

Any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go straight to `to_char` with  `TZM`(time-zone minutes):

```
 select to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'TZM');
 to_char 
---------
 00

select length(to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'TZM'));
length 
--------
      2
(1 row)
```